# How can I check if a javascript file exist without downloading it in bash or python

Tags: python, linux, bash, web, server

How can I check if a javascript file exist without downloading it in bash or python

Comment: `curl -I url` does a HTTP HEAD request instead of a GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python urllib module to check file existence in a given URL. Here's a sample code. The results are saved inside the "results" dictionary.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
urls = ['https://www.codecademy.com/cdn-cgi/challenge- platform/h/g/scripts/alpha/invisible.js','https://www.codecademy.com/idontexist.js']
results={}
for url in urls:
    try:
        ret = urlopen(url)
        if ret.code == 200:
            state="Exists"
            print(url+' : {}'.format(state))
    except:
        state="Not exists"
        print(url+' : {}'.format(state))

    results[url]=state
```

Comment: That's strange. I got the results correctly. Can you check your connection. Script is not blocked by any firewall etc? [https://www.codecademy.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/alpha/invisible.js : Exists
https://www.codecademy.com/idontexist.js : Not exists]

Comment: Some autoformatting happened in the code text. It should be urlopen(url), not URL. Try it on google colab. It works. https://imgur.com/a/vxnz3vh

Comment: It works fine on google colab. I will try it again on my machine. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, glad to hear it worked for you :)